# What to do if my java app is still vulnerable to log4shell after upgrading to the latest log4J?

Tags: java, log4shell

My Java 11 application is being upgraded to fix the log4shell flaw. So first Spring Boot has been upgraded to the latest version.

As my project uses Maven to manage its dependencies, I set the log4j version in the `dependencyManagement` section so that anywhere log4j is used the latest version is picked up :

```
<dependencyManagement>
   
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
      

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

When I give `mvn dependency:tree` a shot to see which library versions are actually used I can see that `log4j-api` and `log4j-to-slf4j` versions are the latest ones (2.17.2) as you would expect :

```
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.5.Final:compile
 |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
 |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
 |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22:compile
 |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
 |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
 |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.4.2.Final:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
 |  |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
 |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.6:compile
 |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.6:compile
 |  |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
 |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.1-GA:compile
 |  +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:7.4.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.11:compile
 |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.noggit:noggit:jar:0.8:compile
 |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
 |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.9:compile
 |  +- net.imagej:ij:jar:1.52q:compile
 |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
 |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.6:compile
 |  +- net.coobird:thumbnailator:jar:0.4.13:compile
 |  +- com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-jpeg2000:jar:1.4.0:compile
 |  |  \- com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.4.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:jbig2-imageio:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parsers-standard-package:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-apple-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-zip-commons:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.21:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.googlecode.plist:dd-plist:jar:1.23:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-audiovideo-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:jar:2.16.0:compile
 |  |  |     \- com.adobe.xmp:xmpcore:jar:6.1.11:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-cad-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:5.2.0:compile
 |  |  |     \- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:jar:1.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-code-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.codelibs:jhighlight:jar:1.0.3:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.epam:parso:jar:2.0.14:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.tallison:jmatio:jar:1.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-crypto-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.70:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-digest-commons:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-font-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.25:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-html-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-html-commons:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |     \- de.l3s.boilerpipe:boilerpipe:jar:1.1.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-image-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-mail-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-mail-commons:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |     +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.8.4:compile
 |  |  |     \- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-dom:jar:0.8.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-microsoft-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.pff:java-libpst:jar:0.9.3:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:5.2.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:5.2.0:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:jar:5.2.0:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:5.0.3:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.06:compile
 |  |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.healthmarketscience.jackcess:jackcess:jar:4.0.1:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.healthmarketscience.jackcess:jackcess-encrypt:jar:4.0.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-miscoffice-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-news-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.rometools:rome:jar:1.18.0:compile
 |  |  |     +- com.rometools:rome-utils:jar:1.18.0:compile
 |  |  |     \- org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-ocr-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-pdf-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.25:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:jar:2.0.25:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-debugger:jar:2.0.25:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.16:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-pkg-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.9:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.brotli:dec:jar:0.1.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.github.junrar:junrar:jar:7.4.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-text-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:jar:1.0.3:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.9.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-xml-module:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.2:compile
 |  |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parser-xmp-commons:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:xmpbox:jar:2.0.25:compile
 |  |  +- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-tika:jar:0.8:compile
 |  |  \- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:jar:0.8:compile
 |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
 |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
 |  +- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:11.0.2:compile
 |  |  \- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:linux:11.0.2:compile
 |  +- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:11.0.2:compile
 |  |  \- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:linux:11.0.2:compile
 |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.6:compile
 |  |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:compile
 |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
 |  \- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:11.0.2:compile
 |     \- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:linux:11.0.2:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.10:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.10:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
 |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.6.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.6.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.6.2:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.6.2:compile
 |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.16:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.58:compile
 |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.2.Final:compile
 |     \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.15.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
 +- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:3.0.0:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:3.0.9:compile
 |  +- nz.net.ultraq.extensions:groovy-extensions:jar:1.1.0:runtime
 |  +- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-expression-processor:jar:3.0.0:runtime
 |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.15.RELEASE:compile
 |     +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.1.26:compile
 |     +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
 |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.1:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.1:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.1:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.1:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.1:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.16:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  +- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:4.0.4:compile
 |  +- jakarta.websocket:jakarta.websocket-api:jar:1.1.2:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |     |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 |     |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:9.2:compile
 |     |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:9.2:compile
 |     |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:9.2:compile
 |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.6.4:runtime
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.4:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.6.4:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.6.4:test
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.6.4:test
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.4:test
 |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:test
 |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
 |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
 |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
 |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
 |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.21.0:test
 |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
 |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
 |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
 |  |  |  \- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
 |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
 |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
 |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.0.0:test
 |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.11.22:test
 |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
 |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.0.0:test
 |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
 |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.16:test
 |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.4:test
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
 |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.6.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.6.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.16:compile
 +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:jar:1.8.1:test
 |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
 |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
 |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.8.2:test
 |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
 |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:jar:1.8.2:test
 |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
 |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
 |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
 +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.197:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:2.6.4:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.16:compile
 |  \- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.7:compile
 \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
```

Yet I am quite surprised that after this log4j upgrade, when I input the payload provided by https://log4shell.huntress.com/ it still logs an input at their site.

The payload is input in a search bar field on a web page. I also tried to input the payload on the login page of my web site but it did not trigger the writing of an entry at Huntress site.

**EDIT (this is an important clue [see my answer])** : Please note that the search bar field triggers a search via SORLJ which requires a SOLR installation on disk. So a version of SOLR was installed on disk and did not change when I removed the older LOG4J version from my program internal libraries.

Can it be that a vulnerable version of log4j is still used somewhere in my project although it does not appear in the dependency tree ? Or does it come from another library (one from the above list) ?

How can I fix this flaw now ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that it's this system that's touching the test site?  Maybe you handle the attack properly, but pass it to a vulnerable service that leaks the attack? Or maybe it's your front end that's logging the data.

Comment: Can you please tell how do you input the payload to the program?

Comment: Thank you John Deters and @ifexploit. The program is web site that runs Jetty. It has a login page backed by a login controller. If the payload is input as password then I can see it at huntress site. When successfully logged in, there is a search bar and once again if the payload is input there huntress site is made aware of it.

Comment: @ifexploit I've just found out that stopping the underlying SOLR server installed on disk removed the call to huntress site and that the login page was not calling them actually (a clean test did not show an entry at huntress). I'll update SOLR server on disk and give feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following the comments I looked again at how the payload is input and discovered that actually the payload did only trigger a bell at Huntress site when it was input in the search field (not in the password field from login page actually) AND that the underlying (installed on disk) SOLR server was running.

Finally updating SOLR binary version installed on disk to the latest one did remove the call to huntress site.

Comment: Good to know you found the underlying problem.